# I've already tried ways But they won't work! it says "a not expected at this time"!

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Here's my code:

```
@echo off
color 0a
set a=0
FOR /L %a IN (0,1,2) DO command (
echo ÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛ
echo Û°°°                Û
echo ÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛ
echo Loading - 2%
)
```

It's the `cmd` that's outputting a not expected at this time!

Answer (score 2):

to use those `for` variables in a batchfile, you have to double the percent signs (and the `command` is not part of the syntax, but tells you to insert a command):

```
FOR /L %%a IN (0,1,2) DO (
  echo ----------
  echo |  note  |
  echo ----------
)
```

A block of commands (enclosed in parantheses) fully qualifies as "command".